# Cannot add Conditional Formatting when saving as XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet format

Tags: excel, automation

I'm dynamically creating an Excel file.

I need to save the file as XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet.

However, the Condtional Formatting won't get added when I saved the file as XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet.

I open the file & I check on the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager and nothing was added.

I'm also not doing any file protection.

```
With .Range("A1")
    .FormatConditions.Delete()
    .FormatConditions.Add(CInt(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue), _
      CInt(XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual), _
      "=" & """OK""").Interior.Color = CInt(eColor.FromArgb_100_51_204_51)
    .FormatConditions.Add(CInt(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue), _
      CInt(XlFormatConditionOperator.xlNotEqual), _
      "=" & """OK""").Interior.Color = CInt(eColor.FromArgb_100_255_0_0)
End With
```

When I'm not saving it in as XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet format, the Conditional Formatting works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the SaveAs xml, but your conditional formatting code.

Running this code, the conditional format is created and saved with the xml file.

```
Sub zx()
    With [A1]
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "OK").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 204, 51)
        .FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlNotEqual, "OK").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Scratch\SOxx", xlXMLSpreadsheet
End Sub
```

I am not sure what `eColor.FromArgb ...` is, so have substituted a RGB call.

Note that `xlXMLSpreadsheet` does not support vba, so if the code is in the active workbook it is not saved with the SaveAs file.

Tested on Excel 2010

Comment: thanks, but this code didn't worked on my side, I guess that when I save to xlXMLSpreadsheet format, formatting condition are being disregarded. If I didn't specify any format then it works perfectly